# SEND_SMS October Policy Update

Tags: android, automation, sms, android-manifest

Evening everyone

I have a query regarding the upcoming changes to the way in which we use permissions inside our Android applications. I've recently received an email from the Google Play Team informing me of the changes to a certain permission I use e.g. SEND_SMS and that it needs to be removed before January 9th 2019.

Now removing this permission will impact my application greatly as one of the functions of my mobile application is to be able to send an automatic text message to another person from the user phone at a set time. Of course the user is completely aware of this and they're the one initiating the setup of the automatic messages from the beginning.

Now removing the SEND_SMS permission from my manifest as stated from google play team will cause this feature to stop working.

My key question is there a way of sending an SMS automcatically without having the SEND_SMS permission set in the manifest?

Thank for your time and your feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you send them an eMail, instead? Which would also be costless, if compared to an SMS, which costs money to the user?

Comment: @KlingKlang - (1) To read sms is more easy then opening email for non pro or basic users. (2) In some countries sms service is free with the call plans by telephony providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way of sending an SMS automcatically without having the SEND_SMS permission set in the manifest?

No, at least in terms of the Android SDK.

It is possible that there are SMS clients that offer an API that you could plug into. In addition, there are hosted services (e.g., Twilio) that you could use.

Comment: CommonsWare thank you for you quick response. These SMS Clients I'm guessing that they wouldn't be free alternative?

Comment: @user3403733: There are dozens, if not hundreds, of SMS client apps. I have no idea if any offer such an API, and I have no idea which are free or paid.

Comment: @user3403733: BTW, it looks like [task automation may now be allowed](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/11/17/tasker-lose-sms-call-functionality-google-security-changes/#1).